# Shorter way of writing singleton-structs

Tags: struct, singleton, go

If I want to create a "singleton" struct, I can do the following:

```
foo := struct{
    bar  func(string, int, bool) error
}{  bar: func(a string, b int, c bool) error {
    // ...
}}
```

as you can see I have to write `bar`'s signature twice. Is there a shorter way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a shorter way.

If the struct really has only one field, you may want to change `foo`'s type:

```
foo := func(a string, b int, c bool) error {
    // ...
}
```